# Why does safari merge canvas drawings on mouse move?

Tags: html, browser, canvas, safari

[The video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bcYVCthNvY) shows the performance problem of safari on canvas drawing.

The drawing takes 100 msec. at average. 
When I move cursor point A to B, other browsers draw the canvas at some points between A and B. But on safari, it generally draws on only near A and near B. 
If the drawing time is so small, safari behaves like the others.

I think when safari does a drawing job, the mouse events are not triggered to the browser.
Is there a way to fix this problem?

My code:

```
public void draw() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    canvas.getContext2d().clearRect(Integer.MIN_VALUE / 2,
            Integer.MIN_VALUE / 2, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    canvas.getContext2d().save();
    canvas.getContext2d().setFillStyle("red");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int x = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
        int y = (int)(Math.random() * 600);
        canvas.getContext2d().fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
    }
    canvas.getContext2d().restore();


    logger.finer("Draw Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

}



    canvas.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            startX = event.getX();
            startY = event.getY();
            dragging = true;
        }
    });

    canvas.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
            if(dragging)
            {
                event.preventDefault();


                int x = event.getX();
                int y = event.getY();

                canvas.getContext2d().translate((-startX + x) / startScale,
                        (-startY + y) / startScale);
                draw();

                startX = x;
                startY = y;


            }

        }
    });

    canvas.addMouseUpHandler(new MouseUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEvent event) {
            dragging = false;

        }
    });
```